# Simplify room creation from comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat

So, often discussions in comments become far longer than they should, and I am going to post two separate feature requests (for the other one see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268472/simplify-room-creation-in-a-comment)). This one suggest that next to each we would get a 'more' icon (e.g. three dots above each other) and in the icon we would have the options:

- Reply
  *This option would simply start a comment with `@username` prefilled.*
- Reply on chat
  *This option would create a chat room, open the chat room and ping the user. Additionally it could be considered to add an auto generated comment so other users can find the chat room as well.*
- Flag
  *The standard flag option would move here to keep the comment section nice and clean.*

Paint created mockup of the way a comment would look on hover:

[image]

Moved the menu to the same location as the 'delete' button for consistency and because it looked too much like an arrow when placed on the left.