# Simplify room creation in a comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat

So, often discussions in comments become far longer than they should, and I am going to post two separate feature requests (for the other one see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268471/simplify-room-creation-from-comments)). This one suggest we would add a new syntax like

> @user [Let's continue the discussion about whether this answer fulfills all the criteria on chat.](new-chatroom)

It's a super simple idea which would make it a lot easier to jump to chat when a discussion start to get out of hand, because right now most users simply wait for the

> "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"

rather than creating a chat room by hand and linking to it. I am not proposing the migration of any comments, although it could be considered to make a copy of the comment thread on chat for ease of use.

[image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96247/is-it-possible-to-import-comments-into-a-chat-room-without-the-link-appearing?rq=1

Comment: I'd add to that, that a name get and stay blue or highlighted so I know user was tagged properly.